# Review queue layout shows name below user gravatar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

The review-queue layout is mildly borked, with names not being displayed *next* to the gravatar anymore, but below it:

[image]

The alignment is surely off and makes for an unnecessarily aired-out appearance. I think this is a bug.

Browser: Google Chrome 47.0.2526.73 m

Comment: MSO duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311890/weird-wrapping-on-review-stats-pages also happens on the revision history view.

Comment: @rene: Thanks. I assume it's better-suited here, as it seems to affect all sites, rather than just [so].

Comment: Agree, I only linked to it so a dev can easy tag status-completed the related questions.

Comment: The MSO dupe suggests narrowing `.user-info .user-details` by 4 px, but it may be better to widen the table instead for consistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved in the latest build.