# Weird formatting in question history of the user's avatar and reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just looked to the history of one of my questions on math.SE and found a weird formatting bug:

[image]

This doesn't look good at all, and I remember that the username and the reputation were next to the avatar.

Comment: probably related to [Review queue layout shows name below user gravatar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270459/260841)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ probably it is also related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270462/what-happened-to-the-reputation-information-box-design and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270461/the-reputation-next-to-a-users-card-has-turned-bold-on-b%CC%B6e%CC%B6t%CC%B6a%CC%B6-all-sites

Comment: @Werner true :)

Comment: You just have too much rep and too many badges now, they don't fit next to the avatar any more.

Comment: Looks like they just made some breaking changes in the design. That's what we're here for, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved in the latest build.